# why the image doesn't save on my code and just saved by admin page?

Tags: django, image

I need to know why the images don't save in the path. I checked from the path and both of static root and media root seems to work good but the image doesn't save, here is the code where you can see what's happening:

**notice**:
the image works fine and has installed by admin page but doesn't save or work by my code.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.image:
            self.image = 'empty.jpg'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'img')
```

urls.py that exists in the project generally

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:login'))
def createProduct(request, slug=None):
    user = User.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if user.user_admin:
        form = CreateProduct(None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateProduct(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                Product.objects.create(
                    user=request.user,
                    name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                    price=form.cleaned_data['price'],
                    digital=form.cleaned_data['digital'],
                    image=form.cleaned_data['image']
                )
                return redirect('store:store')
        return render(request, 'store/create_product.html', {'forms': form})
    else:
        raise ValueError('You have no perm to make something here')
```

Comment: can you show the template form code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are binding upload files to your form in **your template**. Make sure your form looks like this.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/"></form>
```

For more detail visit [django docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form)