# django models imagefield upload_to method not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views, imagefield

I am using create view to create a model instance (product).
Evey thing is working fine bt after doing some new migrations
i can't get the uploaded image, instead getting default image.
I think upload_to method of models isn't working.

i also used this in my urls
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

This is my settigs vars:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
TYPE = [
        ('Sell','Sell'),
        ('Rent','Rent'),
        ('Sell or Rent','Sell or Rent'),
]
owner       = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title       = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
type        = models.CharField(max_length = 12, choices = TYPE, default = 'Sell')
price       = models.IntegerField()
description = models.TextField(default="No Description Given")
image       = models.ImageField(default='default.jpeg', upload_to='product')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('store')
```

and this is my views.py:

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['title','type', 'price','description', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.request.POST)
        owner , created = Owner.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user.owner
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I am getting default image for every new product created.
Thanks

P.S. when i am adding product from admin panel then every thing is working fine.

Comment: You might need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag, this is required when uploading files

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841863/why-the-image-doesnt-save-on-my-code-and-just-saved-by-admin-page/65843506#65843506)