# Django images not uploading

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a blog project where I am able to upload profile picture for each logged in user. Those uploaded profile photos are saving my django files. But for uploading a blog with images its not loading or saving, keeps warning "This field is required".

**Views.py**

```
class CreateBlog(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'App_Blog/create_blog.html'
    fields = ('blog_title', 'blog_content', 'blog_image',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        blog_obj.author = self.request.user
        title = blog_obj.blog_title
        blog_obj.slug = title.replace(" ", "-") + "-" + str(uuid.uuid4())
        blog_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**Models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=264, verbose_name="Put a Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(verbose_name="What is on your mind?")
    blog_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name="Image")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

**Settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Create_blog.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title_block %}
Write a Blog
{% endblock title_block %}


{% block body_block %}
<h2>Start Writing:</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {{ form | crispy }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Publish</button>
</form>
{% endblock body_block %}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843506/11753731

Comment: The link above will solve your problem which is you are not binding your HTML form to accept images/files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>
    {{ form | crispy }}
    {% csrf_token %}
<br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Publish</button>
```